# How do I make a function to run only when the mouse is NOT hovering a specified div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what I got now is:

```
 function()
      {
          setInterval("getSearch()",10000);
      getSearch();

      }
  );
```

But I want this interval to pause if the mouse cursor is placed inside a div on my website. How do I attack this problem? Surely I need to give the div an ID.. But some input on how to make the javascript/jquery part is much appreciated.

EDIT: More of my code.. I'm not quite sure where to insert the code in the answers inside this:

$(
          function()
          {
              setInterval("getSearch()",10000);
          getSearch();

```
      }
  );

TwitterCache = {};
```

function getSearch()
  {

```
        var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=test&refresh=6000&callback=?"; // Change your query here
        $.getJSON
        (
            url,
        function(data)
        {
            if( data.results ) // Checks to see if you have any new tweets
            {
                var i = -1, result, HTML='', HTML2='';
                while( (result = data.results[++i]) && !TwitterCache[result.id] )
                {
                      insert html.. blabla}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` returns a "reference" to that interval you set up, allowing you to stop it with `window.clearInterval()`, and that's what you have to do:

```
var myInterval;

function startMyInterval() {
  if (!myInterval) {
    // It's better to call setInterval width a function reference, than a string, 
    // also always use "window", in case you are not in its scope.
    myInterval = window.setInterval(getSearch, 10000); 
  }
}

function stopMyInterval() {
  if (myInterval) {
     window.clearInterval(myInterval);
  }
}

startMyInterval(); // Start the interval 

jQuery("#myDiv").hover(stopMyInterval, startMyInterval);
```

Comment: I've been trying to implement this in my code, but without any luck. I'll edit my question with more code, and I'd be really glad for some extra advice on where to put it.

Answer (score 1):

Set a global variable

```
var intID;
```

Assign setInterval to this variable

```
intID = setInterval("getSearch()",10000);
```

Set an id for the div

```
$("#divid").hover(function(){
    clearInterval(intID);
},
function(){
    // set the interval again
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
$("#divID").hover(
  function () {
    PauseTheInterValThing()
  }, 
  function()
  {
    setInterval("getSearch()",10000);
    getSearch();
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, and the shortest

Simplest method would be:

```
<div id="yourDiv">
EXAMPLE TEXT
</div>

<script language="Javascript">

var interval = setInterval("getSearch()",1000);

document.getElementById("yourDiv").addEventListener('mouseover', function()
{
clearInterval(interval);
},false);

document.getElementById("yourDiv").addEventListener('mouseout', function()
{
interval = setInterval("getSearch()",1000);
},false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

insert this in your dom-ready function:

```
var inv = setInterval("getSearch",1000);
$('#yourdiv').mouseover(function(){
    clearInterval(inv);
}).mouseout(function(){
    inv = setInterval("getSearch",1000);
})
```